# Storm topology configuration

Tags: apache-storm

How do you provide a custom configuration to a storm topology?  For example, if I have a topology that I built that connects to a MySQL cluster and I want to be able to change which servers I need to to connect to without recompiling, how would I do that?  My preference would be to use a config file, but my concern is that the file itself is not deployed to the cluster, therefore it won't be run (unless my understanding of how a cluster works is flawed).  The only way I've seen so far to pass configuration options into a storm topology at runtime is via a command-line parameter, but that is messy when you get a good number of parameters.

One thought did have is to leverage a shell script to read the file into a variable and pass the contents of that variable in as a string to the topology, but I'd like something a little cleaner if possible.

Has anyone else encountered this?  If so, how did you solve it?

EDIT:

It appears to need to provide more clarification.  My scenario is that I have a topology that I want to be able to deploy in different environments without having to recompile it.  Normally, I'd create a config file that contains things like database connection parameters and have that passed in.  I'd like to know how to do something like that in Storm.

Comment: I guess a fair question to is to ask why not just recompile it? The time to build the jar shouldn't be very large.

Comment: I don't have a compiler on the systems this will be deployed to.  The connections to any database, for example, will be different, therefore I have to be able to change that part of the configuration without needing to recompile.  I'm also not the one who will do the deployment, so it needs to be simple.

My current solution is to leverage a Properties object and read the config from a file.  Then, I populate the storm Config object from this, thus making all of the options available to all of the bolts.  I just prefix the "name" of the bolt to the options for simple segregation.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you, we do this using Flux. http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/flux.html You can put environment specific config in separate files and add them to the includes section?

Answer (score 8):

You can specify a configuration (via a yaml file typically) which you submit with your topology. How we manage this ourselves in our own project is we have separate config files for development and one for production, and inside it we store our server, redis and db IPs and Ports etc. Then when we run our command to build the jar and submit the topology to storm it includes the correct config file depending on your deployment environment. The bolts and spouts simply read the configuration they require from the stormConf map which is passed to them in your bolt's prepare() method.

From http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Configuration.html :

> Every configuration has a default value defined in defaults.yaml in the Storm codebase. You can override these configurations by defining a storm.yaml in the classpath of Nimbus and the supervisors. Finally, you can define a topology-specific configuration that you submit along with your topology when using StormSubmitter. However, the topology-specific configuration can only override configs prefixed with "TOPOLOGY".
>
> Storm 0.7.0 and onwards lets you override configuration on a per-bolt/per-spout basis.

You'll also see on http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/StormSubmitter.html that submitJar and submitTopology is passed a map called conf.

Hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by just providing the config in code:

```
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS, SOME_OPTS);
```

I tried to provide a topology-specific `storm.yaml` but it doesn't work.  Correct me if you make it work to use a storm.yaml.

**Update:**
For anyone who wants to know what SOME_OPTS is, this is from Satish Duggana on the Storm mailing list:

> Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS:  Options which can override
>   WORKER_CHILDOPTS for a topology. You can configure any java options
>   like memory, gc etc
>
> In your case it can be

```
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS, "-Xmx1g");
```

Comment: The storm.yaml file is not for topology specific configurations.

Answer (score 1):

What might actually serve you best is to store the configuration in a mutable key value store (s3, redis, etc.) and then pull that in to configure a database connection that you then use (I assume here you are already planning to limit how often you talk to the database so that the overhead of getting this config is not a big deal). This design allows you to change the database connection on-the-fly, with no need to even redeploy the topology.

Comment: I've considered that approach, but I'd still need a way to tell my topology where the server sits.

Comment: Why? What configuration needs to be done when deploying the topology that can't be part of the computation of a spout or bolt?

Comment: You could have the config in a key value store, dB, zookeeper etc and specify the server (name, port etc) config at cmdline at launch time or in a config file that's included in the resources and distributed with the jar to every node, we do this for several of our configs.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that when you build your topology, you create instances of your spouts and bolts (among other things) and these instances are serialized and distributed to the right places in the cluster.  If you want to configure the behavior of a spout or bolt, you do so when creating the topology before submitting it and you do so by setting instance variables on the bolt or spout that, in turn, drive the configurable behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same issue.I solved it by configuring NFS in my cluster and i put that configuration file in shared location so that it would be available for all cluster machines.Its very easy to configure NFS in linux system [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-centos-6).

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem as u did, and here is my tricky solution:

Use a simple java file as the configure file, say `topo_config.java`, it looks like:

```
package com.xxx
public class topo_config {
    public static String zk_host = "192.168.10.60:2181";
    public static String kafka_topic = "my_log_topic";
    public static int worker_num = 2;
    public static int log_spout_num = 4;
    // ...
}
```

This file is put in my configure folder, and then write a script, say `compile.sh` which will copy it to the right package and do the compilation stuff, looks like:

```
cp config/topo_config.java src/main/java/com/xxx/
mvn package
```

The configuration is achieved directly:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setNumWorkers(topo_config.worker_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

we have seen the same issue and solved it by adding the below per topology

```
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS, "-Xmx4096m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:-CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true");
```

Also verified using Nimbus UI it show like below.

```
topology.worker.childopts   -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:-CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```