# Activate profile while submitting Apache storm topology of a maven project (Without recompiling)

Tags: maven, configuration, apache-storm

I have to activate the profile while submitting the jar to storm like we do for a spring/boot project. like below

`java -jar project-xyz.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`.

It is a maven project with multiple sub modules. we have the resources structured [image: as show here]

Anything that is common to all the profiles will go in the root directory of `resources`, and anything that is specific to a profile (like DB connections) will go in that particular profile directory.

The root directory file will have the `place holders` for profile specific properties and will be replaced by the actual properties defined in profile directory.

Ex: `${mysql.host}` will be resolved to `localhost` when local profile is active.

This final file will be placed in the classpath when we build the jar using

`mvn clean install -P{profile}`

And then the topology is submitted to storm like the following.

`storm jar project-xyz.jar path.to.class.containing.main.method`

The final properties file generated by maven will be read by a property reader, stored and served whenever requested.

```
private static final Map<String, Properties> properties = new HashMap<>();



public static String getProperty( String file, String key )
{
    try {
        if ( !properties.containsKey( file ) ) {
            synchronized ( properties ) {
                if ( !properties.containsKey( file ) ) {
                    loadProps( file );
                }
            }
        }
        return properties.get( file ).getProperty( key );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        throw new PropertyException( "There was a problem getting " + key + " from " + file + ".properties", e );
    }
}


private static void loadProps( String file ) throws IOException
{
    InputStream inputStream = PropertyFileHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( file + ".properties" );
    if ( inputStream == null ) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException( "Property file " + file + ".properties not found" );
    }
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load( inputStream );
    properties.put( file, prop );
}
```

I've already gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061332/storm-topology-configuration) and its different in a way that I use maven and I have to activate the profile instead of providing specific property.

So, is there a way I can activate the profile while submitting the jar to storm somewhat like the following?

`storm jar project-xyz.jar --profiles.active=dev`

If not, what can I do to achieve this without re-compiling the source? Does converting it to a spring boot project help?

Comment: Do you need this property set only during topology submission (all the code up to you calling `StormSubmitter`), or does it also need to be set when the topology workers are executing?

Comment: I did not understand the 2nd part. What do you mean `when the topology workers are executing`?

Comment: I mean does your spout/bolt code also need the property set, or is it purely the code executing during topology submission that reads the property?

Comment: Yes. Every spout/bolt/ component requires the reads the properties like DB connection and other stuff. so yeah it topology components need it while executing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just reread your question, and I think I misunderstood. Am I understanding you correctly that running `mvn clean install -P{profile}` (e.g. `mvn clean install -Pdev`) puts together a config file for the "dev" environment, which is then put into the jar?

Comment: Yes `-Pdev` generates the final files required for reading the properties and will be placed in jar. But now, if I want to run that jar with lets say `staging` environment, I have to re compile with  `mvn clean install -Pstaging` Which I don't want to do. With just one jar(meaning compile once), I want  to run it  once with `dev` and next time with `staging` without recompiling the code.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this as long as you're using Maven to generate a jar containing a single properties file. That jar can only be used in the environment you generated it for.

Instead, you could include all the possible properties files in the jar, and decide which one to read based on a system or environment property.

A better option is probably that you generate the property files separately to the jar, and then put the jar plus property file into Storm. You can pass the property file path to your Storm submission code as a command line argument to your main method. You would then read the properties into memory, and pass them to your bolts/spouts. You need to do this loading eagerly (i.e. read the entire properties at topology submission time, rather than when you need a specific property), so your lazy loading configuration code should be discarded.

You might want something like Flux for convenience:

> To enable property filtering, use the --filter command line option and
>   specify a .properties file. For example, if you invoked flux like so:
>
> ```
> storm jar myTopology-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.storm.flux.Flux
>  --local my_config.yaml --filter dev.properties
> ```
>
> With the following dev.properties file:
>
> `kafka.zookeeper.hosts: localhost:2181`
>
> You would then be able to reference those properties by key in your
>   .yaml file using ${} syntax:
>
> ```
>   - id: "zkHosts"
>      className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkHosts"
>      constructorArgs:
>        - "${kafka.zookeeper.hosts}"
> ```

See the documentation at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/flux.html.